# Having one data trigger for multiple controls

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I want to have one Style DataTrigger inside my window.resources that can be used for multiple expanders. The DataTrigger is bound to an enum value inside my ViewModel, and based on the enum value, I want the the correct expanders to be collapsed. For example: If the enum value is set to "A" then I want only the expander associated with type "A" to be visible, and the rest of the expanders to become collapsed.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="A">
                // In here i would set the expander associated w/ "A" to Visible 
                // and have the rest of the expanders collapsed. Since TargetName is 
                // not allowed within a "Setter" property of a style, I am not sure on how to accomplish this.
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="B">
               // Same concept as above
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Someone may have an answer for you but I don't think XAML is going to support that level of logic.   It is more of a direct pass to screen instruction.  If the Enum value is set via a UI control then you could do it with an event handler or put triggers on the individual Expanders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this (using multiple triggers) with a static resource that caused each Control to 'Collapse' and then having separate 'DataTriggers' inside each Control where the associated enum value causes the visibility to be 'Visible'.

See below (I used canvas in this example):

```
   <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>          
        <Style x:Key="CanvasStyle">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="153" ItemsSource="{Binding IDs}" MaxDropDownHeight="75" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}"/>
    <StackPanel Height="128" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Canvas Height="100" Name="canvas1" Width="100" Background="#FFC70D0D">
            <Canvas.Style>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource CanvasStyle}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="A">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Canvas.Style>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas Background="#FF63C70D" Height="100" Name="canvas2" Width="100">
            <Canvas.Style>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource CanvasStyle}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="B">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Canvas.Style>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas Background="#FF0D55C7" Height="100" Name="canvas3" Width="100">
            <Canvas.Style>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource CanvasStyle}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="C">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Canvas.Style>
        </Canvas>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would be able manually setup Styles for each concrete Expander class, to avoid Trigger code duplication you can use [Style.BasedOn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx) to build a hierarchy of dependent styles:

```
 <Style x:key=ExpanderBaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
   <!-- trigger logic -->
 </Style>

 <Style TargetType="{x:Type FirstExpander}" 
                     BasedOn="{StaticResource ExpanderBaseStyle}"/>

 <Style TargetType="{x:Type SecondExpander}" 
                     BasedOn="{StaticResource ExpanderBaseStyle}"/>
```

Comment: I'm going to try this and see if it works out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I was unable to get this working. what i need is one enum value (in my viewmodel) to set the visibility of 3 controls. I was able to do this by listening to the propertychanged event inside my viewmodel fromt he code-behind and then setting the controls accordingly but wasnt sure if there was a direct xaml solution.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to solve this w/ the solution I posted.